# Is it possible to instantiate a Map container with a tagged record type in Ada in order to use polymorphism?

Tags: dictionary, polymorphism, containers, ada

I want to have a map container which will contain a tagged record type so I wrote this program but GNAT compiler doesn't compile it :

```
type http_response is tagged private;
package map_package is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
    (Key_Type => Unbounded_String,
     Element_Type => http_response);
```

Also I have those compilation error :

```
http.ads:47:04: instantiation error at a-coorma.ads:199
http.ads:47:04: premature use of type with private component
http.ads:47:105: premature use of private type
```

Indeed I want to use polymorphism because my map will contain others tagged record type which inherit from http_response type.

How to correct this code?

If I correct the code like this :

```
package map_package is new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps
    (Key_Type => Unbounded_String,
     Element_Type => http_response'Class);
```

I obtain this kind of errors :

```
http.ads:47:04: instantiation error at a-coorma.ads:195
http.ads:47:04: class-wide subtype with unknown discriminants in component declaration
http.ads:47:04: instantiation error at a-coorma.ads:199
http.ads:47:04: premature use of type with private component
http.ads:47:118: premature use of type with private component
```

Comment: http_request or http_response? the declaration and generic parameter don't match. But if you want polymorphism, I think you need class-wide types : `Element_Type => http_response'class`

Comment: @Brian Drummond : my map will conatin http_response, i've just done a copy-paste error. When I add " 'Class ", I have those errors :http.ads:47:04: instantiation error at a-coorma.ads:195
http.ads:47:04: class-wide subtype with unknown discriminants in component declaration
http.ads:47:04: instantiation error at a-coorma.ads:199
http.ads:47:04: premature use of type with private component
http.ads:47:118: premature use of type with private component

Comment: Please update your question to (a) correct the copy-paste errors, and (b) include the error messages, formatted as code so they're easier to read. While you're editing, you might change "ADA" to "Ada" in the title; it's not an acronym. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I've cleaned up the formatting a bit for you. It's often helpful to insert line breaks in code so readers don't have to scroll sideways to see it all. And since markdown has its own syntax for code blocks and quoted text, it's rarely necessary to use explicit HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [*3.3 Objects and Named Numbers*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-3.html#I1428), "A class-wide subtype is defined to have unknown discriminants, and is therefore an indefinite subtype." Instead of [`Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-6.html), you may be able to instantiate [`Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-13.html).

Comment: See also [*Rationale for Ada 2005: 8.5 Indefinite containers*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-8-5.html).

Comment: Thanks but with your proposition, I have this error : http.ads:47:116: premature use of private type

Comment: Thank for your answers, I found the solution. It was just a problem of visibility.